# Using Wildcards and grep

Tags: linux, bash, unix, grep

How would I find out how many students have an `o` in their account name in my server. Their home directory is in `/home/students`

I have tried

```
grep *o* /home/students
```

this does not work.

Comment: If this is homework, please tag it as such.

Comment: @scorpiodawg The `homework` tag doesn't exist any longer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use

```
ls -1 /home/students | grep o | wc -l
```

-you can not do just `ls -1 /home/students/*o*`  since it will list files inside matched directories.

Answer (score 2):

You could say:

```
find /home/students -mindepth 1 -maxdepth 1 -type d -name "*o*"
```

This would return the directories containing `o`.

In order to find the count, pipe to `wc -l`:

```
find /home/students -mindepth 1 -maxdepth 1 -type d -name "*o*" | wc -l
```

[This](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/ParsingLs) post explains why you shouldn't parse output of `ls`.

Answer (score 1):

This will not list directory contents:

```
ls -1d *o* | wc -l
```

Comment: That's why I like SO - there always are points to learn :p Thank you

Answer (score 0):

Use an array with an appropriate file pattern:

```
o_students=( /home/students/*o*/ )
echo "${#o_students[@]}"
```